# service for seeing what a site looks like in IE7?

Tags: cross-browser

Are there any good services that you can use during development to try out how your site renders in different browsers? We develop on macs. I'd like to be able to pay $20 a month or something like that and be able to VNC in and test my site in IE6, IE7, Opera, etc without having to keep a windows box around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/). It's free, and you can test your site on pretty much any browser imaginable.

Comment: BrowserShots is good, but just be warned that it's not good for rapid development, as the job queue can take a while to get through.

Comment: You can pay money to jump to the front of the queue.

Answer (score 5):

You could use VMware and install your own Windows guest OS and configure them exactly how you like.  Avoid the middleman.

Answer (score 2):

http://browsershots.org/ is a free service

http://litmusapp.com/ has a free service and also some paid services

Answer (score 1):

If you need remote access rather than just screenshots, http://www.browsercam.com does that.

Answer (score 1):

[Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) as others have suggested would work, but Windows in a Virtual Machine may be a better option if you need to test functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Although I dislike Windows, Virtualization is the only way I have found to test near every browser.

Widows 7 Ultimate (XP Mode) => Safari, IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, Chrome, Opera

Add VirtualBox and a Linux guest like Ubuntu => Konqueror

Take note you can't run 2 virtualization softwares concurrently unless someone here specifies how we can assign individual processors to each software.